# Compare two paths in tcl

Tags: tcl

I have two variables with directory paths in them. I would like to see if they are equal in tcl. The problem is that they could be links and I would like to compare the original paths.

```
if { ![string equal -nocase $path1 $path2]} { #do something}
```

I have tried `[file readlink $path1]` to get the original path, but it does not work for directories. Is there a command in tcl like readlink for directories?

Comment: You're probably looking for [`file normalize`](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/file.htm)

Comment: @Glenn Using `[file normalize $path1]` did not get me the original path.

Comment: What does “readlink for directories” mean?

Comment: @Donal I have a path = `/drive/two` which actually links to `/drive/one`. Given `/drive/two`, I want to get `/drive/one`

Comment: If one is a symlink to the other, you can `file readlink` the symlink; I've tested, it works.

Comment: @Donal When I execute [file readlink /drive/two] I get the error "cound not readlink "/drive/two" invalid argument"

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you mean here, but you can make a composite operation.

```
proc readlink_normalize {filename} {
    set f [file normalize $filename]
    while {[file exists $f] && [file type $f] eq "link"} {
        set f [file normalize [file join [file dirname $f] [file readlink $f]]]
    }
    return $f
}
```

The key things are that `file join` is useful here, `file dirname` is good for handling relative links (not all links are absolute) and `file readlink` is only usable when `file type` returns “link”. We leave the handling of non-terminal parts of the filename to `file normalize`. The loop is because a link can point to a link… and we assume that you've not got a link loop; limiting the maximum number of times round the loop is left as an exercise…

---

Once you've got a good normalizer, comparison is just a matter of string-comparing the normalized forms.

Comment: Sorry if I did not make this clear. I do not have a file whose path I am trying to compare. I just have two directories that I want to make sure are the same.

Comment: Which platform? The usual way to do that is to check for identical inode numbers on unix (see `file stat`) or a similar thing on windows via winapi (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364952%28VS.85%29.aspx) or even simpler: Write a file with one directory name, list the directory content with the other name and check if you see it.